# Elasticsearch filter vs term query for many ids

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have an index of documents connected with some product_id. And I would like to find all documents for specific ids (around 100 000 product_ids to be found and 100 million are in total in index).

Would the filter query be the fastest and best option in that case?

```
"query": { 
    "bool": {
        "filter": {"terms": {"product_id": product_ids}
    }
}
```

Or is it better to chunkify ids and use just terms query or smth else?

The question is probably kind of a duplicate, but I would be very grateful for the best practice advice (and a bit of reasoning).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some testing and more reading I found an answer:

Filter query works much much faster as chunks with just terms query.
But making really big filter can slower getting the result a lot.
In my case, using filter query with chunks of 10 000 ids is 10 times faster, than using filter query with all 100 000 ids at once (btw, this number is already restricted in Elasticsearch 6).

Also from official elasticsearch [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/query-dsl-terms-query.html):

> Potentially the amount of ids specified in the terms filter can be a lot. In this scenario it makes sense to use the terms filter’s terms lookup mechanism.

The only disadvantage to be taken into account is that filter query is stored in cache. (The cache implements an LRU eviction policy: when a cache becomes full, the least recently used data is evicted to make way for new data.)

P.S. In all cases I always used scroll.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "`paging`" or "`scrolling`" feature of elastic search query for very large result sets.

Use "`from - to`" query : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html

or "`scroll`" query:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html

I think that "From / To" is a more efficient way to go unless you want to return thousands of results each time (which could be many many MB of data so you probably don't want that)

Edit:

You can make a query like this in bulks:

1. GET my_index/_search
   {
     "query": {
       "terms": {
         "_id": [ "1", "2", "3", .... "10000"  ]  // tune for the best array length
       }
     }
   }
2. If your document Id is sequential or some other number form that you could easily order by, and have a field available you can do a "`range query`"

   GET _search
   {
       "query": {
           "range" : {
               "document_id_that_is_a_number" : {
                   "gte" : 0,     // bump this on each query by "lte" step factor
                   "lte" : 10000 // find a good number here
               }
           }
       }
   }

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am already using scroll (from-to is not my case as I need to go through all of the results for all 100 000 product ids, that I need to find). My question was more which base query would have been more efficient with so many ids to find

Comment: if you already know the Ids, you can query for them explicitly. I would chunk them into reasonable sized batches and perform the query on my own

Comment: Sorry, seems like question was poorly formulated. Yes, I know all 100 000 ids. But it seems like one big filter query as in question works faster as chunks of ids with direct term query. Can it be so? You would recommend to make 100 chunks of 1000 ids and query without filter, just {"query":{"terms": chunk_of_ids}}?

Comment: is the document ID a number or just an identifier (string)?

Comment: I added 2 more options - perhaps they are viable for you. (for some reason can't format the code properly - appologies)

Comment: I don't think that if the  "terms" query array length is very big you will have a large request to send over the wire, but it should be quite fast on the ES side to process. If you can add a "range" field that would be quite convenient to query in bulks. The performance is probably gonna be pretty good