# Elasticsearch: Is there a way how to filter the query by milion(or more) of user ids?

Tags: elasticsearch, filter

Let's say I have an Elasticsearch database index with records/documents for users - every document has user_id field.

Now I also have groups of users - there can be milion+ users in such group.

I want to make an aggregation query based on all documents with user_ids in a certain group.

Is it possible to do something like this or will it hit some sort of limitation?

If it's not possible, is it possible to have e.g. an index that would contain user_ids of a certain group and do some sort of cross query against that index? (something similar to SQL's subquery `WHERE column_name IN (SELECT STATEMENT)`)

```
  "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "user_id": ["userId1", ..., "userId10000000"]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please share your document example or index mapping.

Comment: Is it feasible for you to instead tag each document with one or more group ids?  Or are the groups generated dynamically?

Comment: @JamesDaily the groups are generated and maintained dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

**Regarding terms query** - There is a limit on the number of terms allowed in the terms query which has kept on changing over the different releases of ElasticSearch. This [Github link](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/18829) points to a discussion where it is clearly mentioned that **queries with huge number of terms are slow**. That is one of the reasons there is a limit now which might depend on the version you are using, but for the current version the value defaults to `65,536 terms`.
You can change it in the index settings using [max-terms-count](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html#index-max-terms-count).

So it seems you most probably will have to break your query into chunks. Use the [Scroll API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/scroll-api.html), which maintains a context and is the equivalent of a cursor from other DBs like mongo.

**Regarding filter query** - Filter queries are cached for better performance. Read [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html#filter-context) and [this](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-optimizing-elasticsearch-searches#find-a-friend-in-filters). You might have to keep that in consideration when using multiple filter queries or a single huge filter query.

I would suggest using Scroll API, and finding the appropriate(best performant) batch size for your case. Few other users with similar requirements suggest this too. Read the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51464302/10140124). One thing worth mentioning from the link is the use of range query if your ids are following a particular range. That will definitely be a smaller query and you will not face the issue of terms limit in the query.

As mentioned by you, if by any chance these million terms are coming from another ES document, you can use [terms lookup](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.13/query-dsl-terms-query.html#query-dsl-terms-lookup-params), but then again the limit for that is the same as `max-terms-count`.

Comment: The last part is definitely interesting. What do you think about leveraging multi index search for this? And are there more ways to batch queries?

Comment: I am not sure I understand how you will use multi index search in this use case. Is some of your data coming from another index, or will you restructure your data like that? Regarding the second part, the only time I had to batch queries, we used Scroll API. It might take some time to find the right chunk size for you. If your processing takes too much time, the search context might get lost.

Comment: The user ids could possibly be grouped in another index/document. And yes it'll be a huge data and huge number of user ids. (The target is to filter certain data of a group of user ids (members of the group can change over time as well as the data))